# Загрузить файл с удаленного источника в веб-сервис, отредактировать и послать обратно

Tags: javascript, html5, аудио

Кто-либо имеет опыт подобного?
Есть мой веб-сервис, нужно чтобы трек (музыка) загружался в веб-приложение, проводилась обработка и модифицированный трек лился по нажатию кнопочки на сервер.
Какую технологию можно использовать при данном подходе?
Смотрю на html5 - appcache.

Comment: А зачем это делать на стороне клиента?

Comment: чтобы не нагружать серв